# What will be the best performance scenario between database fetch or php generation

Tags: php

I have a scenario where I just cannot put together which would yield the best performance results. My desire is performance,

I have a few big strings stored in a SQL database

**Example:**

0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,4,4,0,0,0 - This can be (Say 1000 - 20000) characters long(Mostly 0's)

Now I would like to know what will be the best for performance. To keep them in the above format and dong a mysqli fetch or to convert it to something like:

Compressed Example: C0-9,2,4,4,C0-3

Where the number following the - a count. Then to reconvert them before usage. There are mostly huge blocks of 0's so I don't need to worry about condensing other numbers like this.

I know that the second option will have a positive effect on my database sizes. But I am not sure about optimum performance in this case.

Comment: Any compression will improve the performance because there is less data to transfer from disk to memory (inside the MySQL server application) then through the wire (to your PHP script). The one you suggested provides a reasonable compression ratio and it also has the big advantage of keeping the compressed data in a human readable format. Go for it!

Comment: What do these strings represent? I'd have a hunch with so much overhead that you're probably missing a trick, here.

Comment: @Mike, They represent map tiles for a small rpg I am developing as a hobby. So each tile has a number. If there is no tile the number is 0. I might change this in future as well. But am first migrating the original libraries to work via mysql. Once that is done I will take my next step.

Comment: @axiac, It would have another advantage that I can compress / decompress with javascript as well(Mirror functions). Which might help more in future even if gzcompress() would be faster.

Comment: I would be tempted to keep the data out of the database altogether, store them in a file and have the database hold the filename. Easier to edit, stored on the local server and decreases the size of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do compression within PHP itself, which would be more efficient than trying it  yourself.

[link to gzcompress()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php)

The basic idea is that you can compress the data when putting it into the database, then decompress it on the way back out. It will improve performance since MySQL will have less memory in use, and function calls are not hugely costly

Comment: This looks like a good solution for me. And it will save me the time of writing a function as well. That is always welcome.

Comment: No problem. Please remember to mark this as the accepted answer, so it can help others if they are looking for the same answer. Thanks.